# Do I need to update sockets of InvokeSubprogramNode from script

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to write a addon which uses Animation nodes addon. I am able to create different nodes such as Object instance, combine vector, math, transform output, loop and invoke subprogram nodes.

I can able to connect to all nodes except object instance node to subprogram node. Getting exception saying that out of index for invokesubprogramnode.inputs[0].

I found in one of the templates before linking updateSocketifnecessary() is called but i am not able access that function from my addon. I need assistance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still plan to make it easier for other addons to use AN so anything I say here might change in the future, not very soon though.

Before you can create the sockets in the Invoke Subprogram node you need to do three things:

1. Create the subprogram itself (loop, group, script)
2. Tell the Invoke Subprogram node which subprogram it has to invoke:

   `invokeSubprogramNode.subprogramIdentifier = loopInputNode.identifier`

   Every node has an unique identifier (some random string) and every subprogram has an identifier. The identifier of a subprogram is the identifier of its 'owner' node. 'Owner' nodes are: Loop Input, Group Input, Script. Every subprogram has to have exactly one of those.
3. Update the sockets sockets in the Invoke Subprogram node by calling this function: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/blob/master/nodes/system/subprogram_sockets.py#L12

   `animation_nodes.nodes.system.subprogram_sockets.forceSubprogramUpdate()`

Alternatively you can also integrate your code into a Template, which is a special class that makes it easier to create node groups programatically.

Here is an example of a template: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/blob/master/templates/arrange/distribute_instances_on_spline.py

Even if you don't want to subclass a class of AN you can see how the nodes are created there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually saved me. You addon is simply superb of course I did not tried as I am not full time 3D artist but my interest in 3D world makes me to spend little time in it. I am full time software developer in c#.